# Are unstable particles ever "real"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

It's always stressed that internal lines of Feynman diagrams have no physical meaning, that is, they don't actually correspond to anything physical. Where this confuses me is in the case of unstable particles. It seems they can never really be external lines of a Feynman diagram as they must decay. So do fields of unstable particles ever have "on-shell", physical particles in the normal sense?

I often see Feynman diagrams showing products that are unstable, where we then detect the products of their "decay" (for example, the Z or $\tau$). Is this just an approximation, and if it is, isn't this misleading?

Or is creating an unstable particle that then decays a distinct situation from a process with that unstable particle as an internal line?

Comment: "It seems they can never really be external lines of a Feynman diagram as they must decay." This is mixing up a qualitative description of a quirky feature of an approximate and highly limited calculational procedure, with something that actually happens... what does it mean to say that a particle (a concrete thing that an experimentalist detects) is an internal or external line of a Feynman diagram? Why should that distinction matter to anybody who takes measurements?

Comment: I see, so we make unstable particles as products of interactions using Feynman diagrams without worrying too much about the mathematical issue (of unstable particles not really being able to scatter off into infinity)? And they have physical, on-shell excited states?

Comment: The better, calculation-method-independent way to say this is that you simply have a quantum state evolved in time by the Schrodinger equation. At all times, the state is the physical state -- there's no such thing as an off shell or on shell state.

Comment: Conventional Feynman diagrams are a useful way to compute matrix elements between asymptotic states. Strictly speaking, this is _never_ what you actually care about in reality. In reality everything comes in from a finite distance, and you never actually match onto asymptotic free fields. The method is useful when that finite distance is big enough, which occurs when two beams come in, and also when a nearly stable particle comes out.

Comment: Within Feynman diagrams (one particular calculation method) and one particular way of setting up Feynman diagrams, there are particular lines you can draw, which cause you to write down particular terms on a piece of paper (like "$1/(p^2-m^2)$") as part of the calculational scheme. These _terms you write down on a piece of paper_ can be called "on-shell" or "off-shell".

Comment: Having "off-shell" particles is a particular construction in a particular calculational scheme that accounts for some particular quantum effects. It doesn't make sense to say that a state, or something that actually happens, is "off-shell", the state is just what it actually is.

Comment: Thanks! If you're only detecting the decay products, isn't a process like something -> Z Z; then both Z -> e+ e-, just one possible interaction of a more general interaction: something -> Z Z -> e+ e- e+ e-? Where now, the Zs are just an internal line in a Feynman diagram. Why do we ever say we create Zs if we never directly "detect" them.

Comment: The planet earth is unstable against decay into a black hole, through a tunneling process with an extremely long half-life. My feeling is that the planet earth is real.

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to have in the way of thinking a clear distinction between experimental observables  and the mathematical models used to describe the observables. Virtual particles are defined within a quantum field theory model, here as an e[xample electron electron scattering:](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)

[image: virtual]

This diagram has a one to one correspondance with an integral of QFT which will give when calculated the probability of electron electron scattering, the crossection, a measurable quantity experimentaly. The theoretical model fits the data very well.

So within QFT virtual is definde as a line that has all the quantum numbers of the named particle, its mass in the propagator that will be integrated over, BUT the four vector  (special relativity enters here) that describes this internal line is variable within the limits of integration. This is why it is called virtual, because for a real particle the four vector should equal the mass of the real paticle.

So real particles are the ones that are on the mass shell, and these are external lines in the QFT Feynman diagram.

So it is in the hands of the investigator using the QFT model to fit the data, what limits to the integration he/she will use , and of course it depends on the problem at hand to decide which will be real four vectors and which will be virtual, inside the diagram. See the [tau decay feynman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_(particle)) diagram:

[image: tau]

Depending on the experimental data one wants to fit , one can decide about internal or external lines. For example a simple detection of a tau to mu+ neutrino mu,  real particles would only need a diagram (integral) of a  W virtual, i.e.  off mass shell.

It depends on the experimental data fitted what defines virtual or not, what mathematical model is used. It is not simple but it works in fitting the data.

Comment: Ok so I think I understand, the "external lines" are chosen as the particles you'd actually be "detecting". For example though I was reading an old UA2 paper where they discover the Z, and they say the process is p p -> something + Z, where then the Z decays into other products to measure. Shouldn't the outgoing particles be the decay products, where then we'd infer the Z through the resonance from interaction with the Z field?

Comment: I'm talking about equation 1 of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037026938390744X?via%3Dihub if you can get through the paywall. So why are we inferring creating the Z, then it decaying, instead of just using a general Feynman digram with the decay products outgoing (and then measure a possible resonance of the Z). It feels like they're treating the internal lines of a Feynman diagram as physical.

Comment: Our instruments are not fast enough or with such space discrimination that they can "see" a Z , as they can see a muon .http://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2002/Bubblech/guide.html . Our theories though treat the tau decay and the muon decay the same way mathematically. The same is true for the Z. It all depends what data we want to model. The internal lines are not physical, but one can make the hypothesis that the decay products are the Z measred, thus real outgoing, though it will have a width, like all quntum mechanical measurements

Comment: Look at the e+e- showing the resonances, Z included, there the theoretical model accepts Z as virtual  ( and rho etc)http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-cross-section-plots.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand.

Answer (score 3):

The entire formalism of Feynman diagrams and computing scattering cross sections relies on the S-matrix which computes the scattering amplitude of asymptotically free states. So in a purely strict formalism it only makes sense to apply it to particles where both the initial state and final state are absolutely stable. But often times there is a separation of scales such that it is ok to approximate some particles as stable and do your calculation. Generally if your final state particle decays on a timescale that is much larger than the timescale of the hard interaction you are considering then it is ok to treat it as 'stable'. Remember that time and energy and inversely related.

For example in a diagram like this:

[image: e+e- -> mu+ mu-]

The time/energy scale of the Z decay is the same as the interaction that produced the Z so it would not make sense ignore the decay to muons. However the muons themselves, while technically unstable, will take a very long time to decay, they even interact with a detector before they do! So it is a very good approximation to treat them as 'stable' for this calculation and not include their decay in the diagram.